# no sound after upgrade to B450 tomahawk on 18.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I was/am running Ubuntu 18.04 (upgraded from at least 2 previous LTS versions if it matters). Everything was working, including sound.

Just upgraded the motherboard to a B450 Tomahawk (Ryzen 5 2600x). Now sound doesn't work. I have speaker in the "line out" in back off the motherboard and headphones in front, there is no sound from either in tests. So I think this has to be a driver/module issue -- probably.

I tried killing pulseaudio and removing ~/.config/pulse/* and ~/.pulse* then rebooted ... still doesn't work.

lspci shows this for audio:

```
1c:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
1e:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
```

I think the 2nd is what I need. Looking at lsmod, I see:

```
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   106496  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          40960  3
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    81920  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

So I think it should find the generic device first, which should cause it to use the realtek device. Doing "aplay -l" gives me:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

So generic is an ALC892, which I can read that others have made work. Going into KDE's "System Settings" -> Mutlimedia -> AudioVolume -> Advanced, I've turned the GK107 HDMI off and I have "Family 17h HD Audio Controller" set to "Analog Stereo Output" (I've also tried "Analog Stereo Duplex"), but I still don't get sound -- tried with aplay and qmmp.

What else can I look for or do to solve this?
Would it really require a fresh install to detect everything correctly?

Suggestions greatly appreciated. :)

(updated to show device selection)
[device selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYDTT.png)

(update 2)
Just found this in the output of "dmesg", so it looks like it's finding the ALC892 device.

```
[    5.029406] snd_hda_intel 0000:1c:00.1: Disabling MSI
[    5.029412] snd_hda_intel 0000:1c:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    5.041312] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for ALC892: line_outs=4 (0x14/0x15/0x16/0x17/0x0) type:line
[    5.041314] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.041315] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.041315] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    5.041316] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[    5.041317] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Front Mic=0x19
[    5.041318] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Rear Mic=0x18
[    5.041319] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Line=0x1a
[    5.055494] input: HD-Audio Generic Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:1e:00.3/sound/card1/input5
[    5.055578] input: HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:1e:00.3/sound/card1/input6
[    5.055654] input: HD-Audio Generic Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:1e:00.3/sound/card1/input7
[    5.055745] input: HD-Audio Generic Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:1e:00.3/sound/card1/input8
[    5.055849] input: HD-Audio Generic Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:1e:00.3/sound/card1/input9
[    5.055953] input: HD-Audio Generic Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:1e:00.3/sound/card1/input10
[    5.056054] input: HD-Audio Generic Line Out Side as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:1e:00.3/sound/card1/input11
[    5.056251] input: HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:1e:00.3/sound/card1/input12
```

Comment: Can you change the default output device in your sound settings?

Comment: This dialog: https://i.imgur.com/nLt563C.png

Comment: You mean like this? (see update at end of post)

Comment: To follow up for anyone else searching for answer for this problem. I haven't been able to find a solution. Instead, I bought a SB Audigy FX PCIe card, installed it, turned off the onboard audio. Still didn't work, at least I couldn't find it in the audio devices. But I had the KUbuntu disk and tried a live image and it played sound just fine. :) So I installed KUbuntu to an extra partition so I could still get settings off the old root partition and all is good now. It really sucks I had to go buy an audio card when the MB has audio on it, but I like the MB otherwise, so this is what I have.

Comment: The b450 tomahawk with Ryzen 2600x works fine using line out on my system (Ubuntu 18.04 (gnome) with 4.15.0-45). The only major difference I can see is that my ALC892 shows 0/1 under Subdevices. What happens if you try to play something with VLC and switch the device from Audio-> Audio device?